# Twitter API access_token response is blank

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-oauth

I am using [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) module for twitter authentication, and [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) for parsing the object to querystring.

I got the *access_token* and *oauth_verifier* from [oauth/authorize](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/authorize) . I catch callback response using

```
app.get('/', function (req, response) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;
```

> Next, need to [post for access_token](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/access_token) to get the token secret

```
Twitter.post('/https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?'+querystring.stringify(query), function (err, req, res) {
        console.log(err);
        })        
    })
```

The page keeps loading and printing *err* shows:

***Error: JSON parseError with HTTP Status: 401 Authorization Required***

N.B: manually putting the output of */https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?'+querystring.stringify(query)*  in browser produces result

Comment: Hi what's is the value of your parsed query?

Comment: @t3__rry 
oauth_token=*******&oauth_verifier=**** something like that

Comment: Ok so perhaps you could use Express' `res.locals` to be able to re-use your values in another call: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals
I think you problem is that you're using reference from a different scope

Comment: nope... I res.locals not making a difference

Comment: Ok, so you're sure the values you get are valid. What's the error message you get when hitting Twitter's API, if any or is it just timedout?

Comment: @t3__rry sad printing error, response or request is not giving anything....

Comment: @t3__rry I have added the error. Does this gives any hint?